# PHP SHA-512 to Python+C SHA-512

Tags: php, python, sha512

I am working on a website for a game. The accounts are created via the php based website, and the game login server is being prototyped in Python, and will be finalized in C. The problem I am having is that when I hash something in PHP, I am unable to reproduce the same result with the same starting data and salt in Python. I looked through the algorithm in PHP here http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt and compared it to the way I was doing it and noticed that PHP cuts off the null byte at the end. Although, other than that I havent had much luck.

Python:

```
def HashPassword(Salt,Password,Rounds=5000):
    passhash=hashlib.sha512(Password+Salt).digest()[:-1]
    for i in xrange(2,Rounds):
        passhash=hashlib.sha512(passhash+Salt).digest()[:-1]
    return passhash
```

PHP:

```
function HashPW($password, $salt = "")
{
    if(strlen($salt) == 0) $salt = RandChar(16);
    return crypt($password, '$6$rounds=5000$' . $salt . '$');
}
```

Comment: so you're hashing hashes? BTW, hmac is safer than hash

Comment: This might be a result of the `crypt` function. Rather use `hash` or `mhash(MHASH_SHA512, $pw)` and do the looping manually.

Comment: another thing. Why xrange(2, Rounds) instead of xrange(Rounds - 1)? There's one round missing, i guess

Comment: @JBernardo: HMAC is for authentication.  Key stretching doesn't need to withstand the same kind of attacks, so repeated hashes are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some simpler Python code for you.

```
import crypt
def hashPassword(salt, password, rounds=5000):
    return crypt.crypt(password, '$6$rounds={:d}${}$'.format(rounds, salt))
```

Comment: Just change the `format` syntax to `%` syntax.  Something like `'$6$rounds=%d$%s$' % (rounds, salt)`.  Or upgrade to 2.7 or newer.

Comment: nvm its...

    def HashPassword(Salt,Password,Rounds=5000):
        return crypt.crypt(Password,'$6$rounds='+str(Rounds)+'$'+Salt+'$')

Comment: That's somewhat unidiomatic Python -- I recommend using format strings instead, other Python programmers will like you for it.

Comment: My background before python was mostly VB stuff, you would see that most VB dev's prefer concatenation opposed to format strings. However, it is unpopular for a reason, I suppose. Either is fine to me, and I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

String in python doesn't include a null byte at the end.

And `range(2,5000)` will only loop 4998 times.